# serialize JSON with plus sign results in invalid JSON

Tags: json, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10

I'm working with data via an IBM MQ call where a 0 is returned as `+0.0` when this is serialized by ColdFusion 10 (10,0,11,285437) it results in invalid JSON and cannot be deserialized.

```
stPolicy = { "prem": "+0.0" };
serializedData = serializeJSON(stPolicy);
writeDump(isJSON(serializedData));
writeDump(deserializeJSON(serializedData));
```

This outputs `NO` for `isJSON` and an error when trying to deserialize `JSON parsing failure at character 9:'+' in {"prem":+0.0}`.

I'm able to work around this by replacing all `+0` to `0`, but I'm guessing this is a bug in ColdFusion. Has anyone else had this issue and implemented a better fix?

Bug report filed: [Bug #3632972](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3632972)

Comment: https://bugbase.adobe.com/ thx

Comment: @Henry bug entered https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3632972

Comment: Bloody hell... exactly when will all these bugs in ColdFusion's JSON handling end? I think they need to start from scratch & do it properly. Needless to say I will vote for this.  It is broken on CF9 and CF10, btw. But works fine on Railo. And even OpenBD.

Comment: I wonder if there is a CFC on github or somewhere that someone is working on? We need a single place to collaborate on this solution.

Comment: @JamesMohler Ben Nadel started a project here https://github.com/bennadel/JsonSerializer.cfc

Comment: How can there be so many bugs for such an expensive product? Srsly Adobe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe has the bug listed as fixed in their [bug database](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3632972), but it has not yet been released. Here's the fix I came up with. Simply replace the `+0` with `0`

```
private string function serializeJSONFixCF10(required string serializedData) {
  return replace(arguments.serializedData,'+0','0','all');
}
```